# SQL Server: encoding of hex value in XML?

Tags: sql-server, xml

When I dump a hex value into XML output in SQL Server, e.g.

```
0x103319FF9ABAF2EC14E1432479DA3CDBC8B2DEF8
```

I get:

```
/DNcECEQkcDhcAkP/56jm/XHKQk=
```

This looks like it has been encoded to base64, but I tried different converters and wasn't able to reconvert the second value into the first. Does anyone know how SQL Server encodes the hex value in XML?

Comment: Me stupid took wrong input string in HASHBYTES and wondered about non-matching values. Me triple checks in future before asking questions. Me blushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This looks like it has been encoded to base64, [...] wasn't able to reconvert [...].
> Does anyone know how SQL Server encodes the hex value in XML?

This is the standard behaviour with BLOBs (binary data). It wasn't in very early times, but - AFAIK - since SS2005 it is:

Any binary value is implicitly converted to a `base64` representation:

```
DECLARE @YourBinary VARBINARY(MAX)=0x103319FF9ABAF2EC14E1432479DA3CDBC8B2DEF8;

DECLARE  @xml XML =
(
    SELECT @YourBinary FOR XML PATH('test')
);

SELECT @xml;
```

--returns

```
<test>EDMZ/5q68uwU4UMkedo828iy3vg=</test>
```

This value is implicitly re-converted to a **real binary**, when you specify the correct target type:

```
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/test/text())[1]','varbinary(max)')
```

Might be, that you are mixing up the *real binary value, which is **shown to you as a hex string*** and a *hex string, which is a string (a **line of characters**) actually*.

Just look at numbers. In XML you see the written number, but - as you surely know - a numeric data type is not stored as a line of digits. Within XML any data is converted to a **string representation with a defined format**. Reading this data needs the **re-conversion back into the original data type**.

If you really need the hex string as a line of hex-characters, you can go with Dan Guzman's suggestion.

### UPDATE: Special treatment with `FOR XML RAW` or `FOR XML AUTO`:

After a discussion with Bogdan Sahlean I'd like to add, that in most cases you'll want to use `FOR XML PATH`. But - in some cases - it can be a choice to use `EXPLICIT`, `RAW` or `AUTO` (although such cases are rare...). These modes need a special mark how to deal with binary data:

```
SELECT 0x01 AS x FOR XML RAW, BINARY BASE64 --breaks without ", BINARY BASE64"
```

Some details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-the-binary-base64-option)

Comment: Besides the fact that my question was crap, I rate this as the answer as it might explain MS SQL XML encoding and conversion issues best. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

One method is with the hexToBinary function:

```
DECLARE @table TABLE(BinaryValue varbinary(MAX));
INSERT INTO @table(BinaryValue) VALUES(0x103319FF9ABAF2EC14E1432479DA3CDBC8B2DEF8);
SELECT
    CAST('' AS XML).value('xs:hexBinary(sql:column("BinaryValue"))', 'varchar(MAX)') AS HexString
FROM @table;
```

This will return the string of hex digits without the `0x` prefix:

`103319FF9ABAF2EC14E1432479DA3CDBC8B2DEF8`